# Where to find package WINE in .deb

Tags: wine

Where can I get package WINE 1.6 in format .deb? I have no capabilities to make it myself from achives(xz or bz2) . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has its own site with packages. Wine for 16.04 can be found [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=wine&searchon=names). You can also find all the available wine DEB packages on [dpkg download page](https://pkgs.org/download/wine). Wine 1.6 would be for Ubuntu 16.04.

- Original [amd64 version](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/wine_1.6.2-0ubuntu14_amd64.deb.html) for Ubuntu.
- Original [i386 version](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/ubuntu-universe-i386/wine_1.6.2-0ubuntu14_i386.deb.html) for Ubuntu.